# Why doesn't 'fs' work when imported as an ES6 module?

Tags: node.js, fs, es6-modules

Why do I get errors like these when I try to use the new Node.js support for ES6 modules (e.g. with `node --experimental-modules script.mjs`)?

```
// script.mjs
import * as fs from 'fs';

// TypeError: fs.readFile is not a function
fs.readFile('data.csv', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (!err) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
// TypeError: fs.readdirSync is not a function
fs.readdirSync('.').forEach(fileName => {
    console.log(fileName);
});
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You must use `import fs from 'fs'`, not `import * as fs from 'fs'`.

This is because (*at least from the point of view of mjs files*) the `'fs'` module exports only one thing, which is called `default`. So if you write `import * as fs from 'fs'`, `fs.default.readFile` exists but `fs.readFile` does not. Perhaps the same is true of all Node.js (CommonJS) modules.

Confusingly, in TypeScript modules (with @types/node and ES5 output), `import fs from 'fs'` produces error

```
error TS1192: Module '"fs"' has no default export
```

so in TypeScript you must write `import * as fs from 'fs';` by default. It appears this can be changed to match the way mjs files work using the new [`"esModuleInterop": true` option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#support-for-import-d-from-cjs-form-commonjs-modules-with---esmoduleinterop) in tsconfig.json.

Comment: `fs` is a core module in node, you don't need to import it at all. It's always there.

Comment: Failure to import fs will cause `ReferenceError: fs is not defined`, even if it's not an .mjs module.

Comment: TypeScript is for type safety, so you should import your types. It's similar to using `var fs = require('fs');` but we have to do some trickery for TS to get it just right. I was able to get it using `Import * as fs from 'fs';`, but not `Import fs from 'fs';`. I have been able to do the latter with most node modules when enabling the `esModuleInterop` and `allowSyntheticDefaultImports`, but not fs :(  This one does work, for example: `import path from 'path';`

Answer (score 6):

We can simply import like this it in our code

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
```

and it is perfectly working for me, give it a try

Comment: My question has those exact characters on the first line of code (in the same order too)

Answer (score 2):

Adding `"esModuleInterop": true` in my `tsconfig.json` file fixed the issue