# fs.readFile() or fs.readFileSync() not a function exception but why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am using the `fs` module with the following import code

`import fs = require('fs')`

The code runs until encountering this exception at the second line of the TypeScript codes below

```
const filePath = 'data/soylent-uist2010/userSegments.json'
const seg = fs.readFileSync(filePath, {
  encoding: 'utf8',
})
```

However, if I supply the `path` argument of `readFileSync` as a raw string (as below), it works as normal (value is assigned).

```
const seg = fs.readFileSync('data/soylent-uist2010/userSegments.json', {
  encoding: 'utf8',
})
```

The error stack trace is as below,

```
Viewer.tsx:155 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function
    at Viewer.<anonymous> (Viewer.tsx:155)
    at step (io.ts:106)
    at Object.next (io.ts:106)
    at io.ts:106
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (io.ts:106)
    at Viewer._this.loadFiles (Viewer.tsx:135)
    at Viewer.<anonymous> (Viewer.tsx:98)
    at step (io.ts:106)
    at Object.next (io.ts:106)
```

A longer code snippet is as below. I suspect if the `async` keyword (in the class method) would require an `await` keyword before `fs.readFile()`

```
  loadFiles = async () => {
    this.setState({ pages: [] });
    const {
      pageNumbersToLoad,
      pathInfo: { pdfDir, pdfRootDir }
    } = this.props;
    const fullDirPath = path.join(pdfRootDir, pdfDir);
    const pdfPath = path.join(fullDirPath, pdfDir + ".pdf");
    **const seg = fs.readFile(...);**
```

Comment: FYI - 'fs' is for FileSystem, meaning it will only work in a Node.js environment and not in a website.

Comment: `import fs = require('fs')` isnt that a SyntaxError? Try `const fs = require("fs")` or `import * as fs from "fs";`

Comment: Thanks evegeni! Wanted to add that all codes are inside a class function, maybe it is not the proper place to declare `filePath`?

Comment: Thanks Steven and Jonas, the project is inside Parcel + TypeScript (es5). I am very new to front-end dev so not sure if it's a Node.js env.

Comment: @XinQian That will depend on where you are using it. It can be used in build steps, because you build using Node.js, but it can not be used in your client code that's bundled for websites.

Comment: Current it's build step so I suspect the reason is the async statement. Should I add `await` keyword before fs.readFile() or fs.readFileSync()?

Comment: Turns out our codebase is relying on electron. From a colleague, "electron lets you mix nodejs code and browser code. you can only do browser things and therefore cant access the filesystem. you have to import {} from '*.json" or require and parcel will load stuff for you. You can't write to a file though.". So for this question, the decision is to abandon fs.readFile() at this moment.

Comment: oooh, electron! that explains it. I agree with abandoning fs.

Answer (score 4):

Because `fs` does not have a default export you need to import like so:

`import * as fs from 'fs'`

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing javascript standards.

If you choose to use the older javascript **ES5** standard, then your code should like like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

However, if you're going to use the newer **ES6** (and beyond) standard, you would use the [import statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) like so:

```
import fs from 'fs';
```

You seem to be combining the two, hence your error.

***NOTE:*** Because `fs` has a default export that exports the `fs` module, you don't need the `import * as` syntax. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50661510/why-doesnt-fs-work-when-imported-as-an-es6-module) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: ES6 way throws: "fs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default().readFileSync is not a function"